# Prove using the axioms that $x>0$ implies $-x<0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing, real-numbers, axioms

How to prove equations that if $x>0$, then $-x<0$ using the axioms of the real numbers $\Bbb{R}$ (if $x \in \Bbb{R}$)?

My university lecturer gave this as an exercise and I am stuck on which axioms to use. I was thinking you could use O4 but that uses the condition that $z>0$ which means you can't set $z=-1$.

[Here are the axioms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrxIo.png)

Please help!!

Comment: try using O3...

Comment: An axiom is $a<b$ and $c<0$ implies $ac>bc$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Axiom O3, we have that, since $0<x,$ $0+(-x)<x+(-x).$ Now, by Axioms F3, F4, we have that $-x<0.$

Comment: Can you just say that $x>0$ is the same as $0<x$ without justifying it by using an axiom?

Comment: @Tikak, the symbol "$\gt$" does not appear in any of the axioms. The equivalence of "$x\gt0$" and "$0\lt x$" is more a matter of notational definition.

Comment: @Tikak, $a>b$ is defined as $b<a.$

Answer (score 1):

If $x, -x>0$, then $0<x = x+0<x+(-x) = x-x=0$. If $-x=0$, then $0=x-x=x+(-x)=x+0=x>0$. In both cases, $0<0$, so we must have $-x<0$.

Answer (score 1):

Use O3: start with $x>0$ and add $-x$ to both sides